# TypeError: data.reviews is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

What's the problem? Is this the fault of the add-on, or maybe I didn't add something to the given file in the project?

here you can see the error that appears to me on the browser after firing the code

```html
render/<
src/components/Reviews.js:10

   7 | return (
   8 |   <InfoConsumer>
   9 |     {data => {
> 10 |       return data.reviews.map(person => {
     | ^  11 |         return <ReviewCard key={person.id} person={person} />;
  12 |       });
  13 |     }}
```

this is what my Reviews.js file looks like and I put a piece of my code underneath

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { InfoConsumer } from "./context";
import ReviewCard from "./ReviewCard";

class Reviews extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <InfoConsumer>
        {data => {
          return data.reviews.map(person => {
            return <ReviewCard key={person.id} person={person} />;
          });
        }}
      </InfoConsumer>
    );
  }
}

export default Reviews;
```

And this is what reviedcard.js looks like, I don't know where the error is, as soon as I use  in the details.js file

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { InfoConsumer } from "./context";

class ReviewCard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { id, name, avatar, comment } = this.props.person;
    return (
      <InfoConsumer>
        {data => (
          <div className="media mt-5">
            <img
              src={avatar}
              alt={name}
              style={{ width: "40px" }}
              className="mr-3"
            />
            <div className="media-body">
              <h5 className="mt-0">{name}</h5>
              <p>{comment}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </InfoConsumer>
    );
  }
}

export default ReviewCard;
```

Comment: Important fact to observe: your post _has no question_ right now. So: please read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post accordingly.

Comment: As the error says, `data.reviews` is undefined. There aren't enough details in this question to see what the contents of `data` are, but the error tells us that `reviews` is not a property of your `data`. Is that coming from an API call? If so, then what your code and what the API is returning aren't matching up.

Comment: @Jacob thanks, I found an error, typo.